# Rails Javascript, images not being linked or loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image

I am following the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DR5JLZ2Qgg tutorial, however my star images when writing reviews fail to show up. 
In the Jquery file:

```
$.fn.raty.defaults = {
 ...
starHalf     : 'star-half.png',
starOff      : 'star-off.png',
starOn       : 'star-on.png',
 ...
};
```

On the chrome console

```
...  
<img alt="5" src="/assets/star-off.png" title="gorgeous"> 404 error
```

The jquery script appears to be loaded, but the images are not visible.
I saved images in the /assets/images folder, and I have also added them to the /assets folder just in case

Other images I have loaded are from a "/dev-assets" folder when checked with the chrome's inspect

Edit, There are many other images my app loads correctly, all the images are in the /assets/images folder. It's just these star images don't load

Comment: maybe incorrect path.. maybe you might need to add `assets` folder to rails app

Comment: You probably need to use a finder helper like asset_path etc.

Comment: What do you mean, asset_path was not in the original tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at development.rb and found a line

```
 config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"
```

I removed the line and the stars started working. I don't know what this is and I hope nothing becomes broken because of it.